# Force string.format to set null value for a query

Tags: c#, string, null, string.format

I have this:

```
int id = 10;
long partnerId = 20;
long? groupId = null;
DateTime startDate = Datetime.Now.AddDays(-5);
DateTime endDate = Datetime.Now;
bool isTesting = true;
bool isActive = false;

query = @"SELECT Vita as VitalLevel,count(distinct ccrid) as Answers, Vitald as VitalType
                      FROM CORE.vRecipientsc rd
                      INNER JOIN Recipiendy rs ON rs.CRRID = rd.RID
                      INNER JOIN RecipientStungs rsvr ON rsvr.StudyId = rs.Id 
                      WHERE SBURID = {0} 
                      AND ({5} IS null OR {5}=SbuGroupRID)
                      AND rs.DTUTC_Created >= '{1}' 
                      AND rs.DTUTC_Created <= '{2}'
                      AND rsvr.VitalTypeId = 8 
                      AND rsvr.VitalValue <> '' 
                      AND (rd.isTesting = {3} or rd.isTesting = 0)
                      AND rd.IsActive= {4}
                      GROUP BY rsvr.VitalValue, rsvr.VitalLevel, rsvr.VitalTypeId";

String.Format(query, new object[] {
            partnerId, startDate, endDate, Convert.ToInt32(isTesting), Convert.ToInt32(isActive), groupId
        });
```

Then I have a connection with the database and multiple queries executing, but when I execute the query the null values in the string.format are replaced for empty spaces, I want that the line replaced for the groupId variable set null directly. Can I make this work with C#?

Comment: and better use parameters to set null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [String.Format Method (String, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) and [??](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) for nullable values.

```
String.Format(query, partnerId, startDate, endDate, Convert.ToInt32(isTesting), Convert.ToInt32(isActive), groupId ?? "null");
```

Or you could use same method and ternary operator

```
String.Format(query, new object[] { partnerId, startDate, endDate, Convert.ToInt32(isTesting), Convert.ToInt32(isActive), groupId != null ? groupId.ToString() : "null" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the line itself as the last parameter:

Replace `AND ({5} IS null OR {5}=SbuGroupRID)` with `{5}` and set the value of the last parameter to `groupId.HasValue ? string.Format("AND ({0} IS null OR {0}=SbuGroupRID)", groupId) : string.Empty`

You can move it into another variable as well before the string of the query and just use that variable as the last parameter.